# What are the properties of interface refrence variable? Why the following Code /Snippet Fails?

Tags: java, interface, iterator

Execuse my ignorance.New to Interface Concept.Kindly help me out with the concepts involved by considering the following code:

```
    import java.util.*;
    class TestCollection1
   {
      public static void main(String args[]){

      ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();
      al.add("Ravi");
      al.add("Vijay");
      al.add("Ravi");
      al.add("Ajay");

     ***Iterable  i=al.iterator();
     Iterator itr=i;***
     /*The following  code above has been written intentionally to check scope and 
        properties of Iterable i ...Output Fails in this Case*/
     Iterator itr=a1.iterator();
      //On using above and deleting iterable part ,We get the desired Output                   
     while(itr.hasNext()){
     System.out.println(itr.next());
         }
       }
     }
```

The output Fails :

1.Why does The Output Fails in 1st Case .Iterable is an Interface which has method iterator().Hence Its refrence variable should be able to store iterator object/refrence/iterator returned by a1.iterator();

2.Iterator Interface which doesn't even have iterator() method works fine .How?

Comment: `a1` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Iterable i=al.iterator();
```

fails, because `al.iterator()` returns an `Iterator` (that's the interface that has the `hasNext()`, `next()` & `remove()` methods), not an `Iterable` (that's the interface that has the `iterator()` method).

```
Iterable i = al;
```

will work, since `al` is an `ArrayList`, which implements the `Iterable` interface.

That's also the reason

```
Iterator itr = al.iterator();
```

works - the `Iterable` interface has an `iterator()` method.

Comment: iterabe i is a refrence variable.Can't we store a1.iterator() output in it.??

Comment: @sociopath You can only assign to `i` objects of classes that implement the `Iterable` interface. `a1.iterator()` implements `Iterator`, which is a different interface.

Comment: Excuse my knowledge.Just to Clear doubt:  As per java doc  regarding a1.iterator() : a1 is object of  ArrayLIst Class which implements Collection interface which extends iterable interface which has iterator() .Thus we can use a1.iterator()....which Proves that ArrayList Class implement Iterable() Interface .And as per ur comment "You can only assign to i objects of classes that implement the Iterable interface"

Comment: @sociopath You didn't try to assign `a1` (or `al` - whatever it is called) to `i` - that would work. You tried to assign `a1.iterator()`, which is an `Iterator`, not an `Iterable`.